TEI XML Batch Processing of Attributes in Oxygen
I have a very large TEI:XML of an early modern manuscript in which specific entities have been tagged with  or . Now I want to add attributes to those elements like @key oder @id.
Since the manuscript is very repetitive and often contains the same elements just with slightly different spelling variations I was looking for a way to batch process the tagging workflow.
Currently I´m using the XPatch Command //persName to get a list of all  elements. Then I look for similiar entries and use Refactoring/Add Change/Attributes and write another XPath for the specific person to add the desired attributes.
Is there an easier way? Like selecting all entries in the XPath Results and just add the attributes without the Refactoring process?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I would advise you to create your own xml refactoring operation using a custom xslt or xquery update script.
Some sample custom xml refactoring operations I implemented in the past:
https://github.com/oxygenxml/dita-refactoring-examples
